# How to comment out multiple lines at once in Notepad++?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, comments

In Eclipse it is possible to comment out multiple lines at once by selecting them and executing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>:

`// helloworld`

Is this possible in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) as well instead of typing <kbd>/</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> in front of each individual line?

Comment: If the shortcut aren't working to (un)comment: delete `langs.xml` and try again.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Select desired lines and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. This will toggle comments on and off.

Also, I've just recently become a fan of <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Click</kbd> to select multiple lines and just manually comment those lines with `//`.

I've found the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Click</kbd> trick to work well with Visual Studio, JetBrain products, Notepad++ but not Eclipse.

Comment: The `ALT + LMC` and subsequently `//` works in `.scala` as well. To uncomment: `ALT + LMC` and subsequently two times `DEL`

Comment: Select multiply lines and `Ctrl+Q` is faster than multiline select and `//`

Comment: "This will toggle comments on and off" as VitaminYes wrote. If you want to re-commment the commented lines, see @john-robertson 's response http://superuser.com/a/916881/342669

Comment: For the people, with who `CTRL+Q`didn't work, you have to choose the lanuage of your file from the `language menu`, otherwise notepad++ will not know what is the comment type you want.

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> does not quite work as expected, though. If there is already a comment in there, the comment is un-commented. For example, select a bunch of `C++` code with one of those selected lines being `// This is amazing code!`. Now that line will be converted to `This is amazing code!`. The feature is "doing what it says on the tin", just not what was expected! Personally, I'd expect that if >50% of selected lines were not commented then comment them all, and vice versa.

Answer (score 28):

Also <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> works well in Notepad++ to comment. If you had existing comments in a long block you are commenting, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> will uncomment your actual comments, where <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> just add another level of // in front. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> removes a single line comment from the selection.

Comment: This is a [Ctrl-Q bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1022270/632951) actually. If there are half commented lines and half uncommented lines, Ctrl-Q should comment them all, then uncomment them all, then comment them all again.

Comment: Verified that CTRL+K works as well to comment out in Notepad++

Answer (score 14):

In notepad++ I believe that the shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> for commenting the code.

You can go to `Settings > Shortcut Mapper` to change this to match your preference.

The default for a block comment is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. So you can highlight the block of code then use this shortcut.

Comment: I have created a `.html` file and executing the command results in `<!-- -->`, but nothing happens in a `.scala` file

Comment: `CTRL + SHIFT + Q` results in `/*  */` in a `.java` file

Comment: These are the different comments for different languages. Here is a list of supported languages natively in Notepad++: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B#Programming_languages

Comment: So how do you uncomment in HTML?

Comment: @DanSmith, Dam I can't uncomment the commented code. **What's the opposite of Ctrl-Shift-Q**?

Comment: user *Ctrl+Shift+K* to uncomment

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer only using the mouse, install the "Customize Toolbar" plugin from the plugin manager, and add "Single Line Comment" and "Single Line Uncomment" buttons.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a macro with a custom shortcut 
(CTRL+Q didn't work on javascript inside a .html document)

The trick works for a single line comment only.

**Create the macro :**

1. Macro > Start recording
2. place the cursor in your doc and type:
   `//`
3. Macro > Stop recording
4. Macro > Save
5. Give a name and select your prefered keyboard shortcut.

**To quickly comment a line :**

Place the cursor at the beginning of the line to comment and press the shortcut you defined for the macro.