# How to comment multiple rows with # on Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

[There is a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/790353/how-to-comment-out-multiple-lines-at-once-in-notepad) but it shows how to comment with `//`  since I'm using `notepad ++` to view Python scrips the comment needs to be `#` and not `//`

How can i comment multiple rows with `#` ?

Comment: Ctrl + Q  works fine. Is the language defined as Python?

Comment: @Toto how do I define the language?

Comment: As simply as Menu "Language > P > Python"

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003761/notepad-add-to-every-line which, by the way, is GENIUS functionality I never knew existed until today.

1. Using your mouse/keyboard, click to put the cursor at the start of the first line you want to add text to the beginning of
2. Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag your mouse immediately down (or use your keyboard <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys). You will see the cursor line extend down each line you highlight.
3. Type the text you wish to enter
4. Done.

---

**Highlighted lines**

[image]

**Text added to multiple lines simultaneously**

[image]

Comment: Most WYSIWIG editors have that functionality, I use it a lot in SSMS when running  a sproc multiple times.